# Google Sheets Email Daily Report based on cell values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to only display rows that are blank in column F and email them.
Trying to get all rows that don't have equipment ordered and send them in a email daily.

I'm using this script that uses [SheetConverter](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter).
Here is what my [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtIm0.png) looks like. Here is what my [email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXFdz.png) looks like.

```
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{
var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, '', {htmlBody : HTML});
}
function doGet()
{
var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();

var emailUser = '****@gmail.com';

var subject = 'Test Email';

convSheetAndEmail(dataRange, emailUser, subject);
}
```

Edit
Do you mean like this @Yash, I keep getting error cannot find getsheet in object

```
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{
  var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, '', {htmlBody : HTML});
}
function doGet()
{
   var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    if (data[i][5] === ""){

  var labels=new Array;
    labels.push([data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4], data[i][5], data[i][6], data[i][7]]);  

  var emailUser = '****@gmail.com';

  var subject = 'Test Email';

  convSheetAndEmail(labels, emailUser, subject);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer. check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know where you are facing the issue. Check this code, it will help you.
First sort the values of `F` column and select the unfilled cells from `A to H` Sort the `F` column in descending and then first column in ascending (just to get range in sequence).

```
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{
  var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, '', {htmlBody : HTML});
}
function lastValueOfColumn(column) {
  var iLastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
  var aValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + "1:" + column + iLastRow).getValues();
  for (; aValues[iLastRow - 1] == "" && iLastRow > 0; iLastRow--) {}
  return iLastRow;
}
function doGet()
{
  var iLastRowOfH = lastValueOfColumn('H');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A1:H' + iLastRowOfH).sort([{column: 6, ascending: false}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  var iLastRowOfF = lastValueOfColumn('F') + 1;
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A' + iLastRowOfF + ':H' + iLastRowOfH);
  var emailUser = '****@gmail.com';
  var subject = 'Test Email';
  convSheetAndEmail(data, emailUser, subject);
}
```

Comment: @MarkLester If this answer will be helpful to you then upvote it to raise the correct answer above all and that helps other also who are facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, and the one I know, is to :
get the values in an Array using

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
```

then to make a loop

```
for (i in data) {
```

in this loop to check if the items ordered (`data[i][5]`) is equal to `null` that you're looking for. If yes, then push that row to an array

```
var labels=new Array;
label.push([data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4], data[i][5], data[i][6], data[i][7]]);
```

then having all your data in this array, you can populate a panen Ui with label using a for loop.

An **alternate way** is to use the "Query" formula on `getRange()` which directly gives you filtered data

Finally your script looks like this :-

```
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{
    var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, '', {htmlBody : HTML});
}
function doGet()
{
    var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    var labels=new Array;
    for (i in data) {
        if (data[i][5] === ""){
            labels.push([data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4], data[i][5], data[i][6], data[i][7]]);  
        }
    }
    var emailUser = '****@gmail.com';
    var subject = 'Test Email';
    convSheetAndEmail(labels, emailUser, subject);
}
```

Comment: I keep getting error cannot find getsheet in object

Comment: @MarkLester Updated my answer. check it

Comment: @ Yash I keep getting error, It is pulling the right data----------------------------                      
TypeError: Cannot find function getSheet in object Wed Apr 25 2018 20:06:28 GMT-0500 (CDT),***@gmail.com,5555,Vance Thompson,1-AP ceiling Mount,,Sat Apr 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT),. (line 179, file "Code", project "SheetConverter")

Comment: @MarkLester have you tried my updated answer?? I've done few changes including the use of `getActiveSpreadsheet()` instead of `getSheet()` and if still getting the same error, show me the error line...

Comment: @ Yash here is the error  ---  TypeError: Cannot find function getSheet in object Sun Apr 29 2018 12:36:43 GMT-0500 (CDT),****@gmail.com,7878,Arthur Freeman,2-Switches,,,. (line 179, file "Code", project "SheetConverter")